Can requesting to correct a minor error after acceptance lead to rejection of the submission?
One of my papers recently got accepted in a journal. While sending me the proof, they mentioned that I can make changes only to the copyedited portions in the manuscript. They also mentioned that extensive changes will be reviewed by the editor and may delay publication.  I noticed a typo error in a different portion of the manuscript than the copyedited portions. I corrected it and sent the proof response. I tried to justify why it is important to rectify the typo.
I am now worried as six days have passed since the proof was submitted and it is not published yet. Is there any chance of rejection ?

Is there any chance of rejection? -> No

Six days and you're already worried? Chill out, people have lives too.

There is a risk they will not accept your typo correction and a risk of added delay if they send to the editor.
They will not go back on the overall acceptance of the manuscript. Congratulations!

Journal publications often go through a series of steps, from an initial acceptance to different rounds of revision. From your text, it apparently seems it has passed initial screening. Maybe in couple of weeks period, you might get email(s) about major/minor revision of the manuscript. Normally, few typos do remain even in the final and published versions, so there is no need to worry about it. Normally, it is the novelty and relevance of the idea and research presented in the manuscript that leads to acceptance in a journal. Regarding, the error you pointed out, I am sure in your revised version whenever it is called, you can rectify that. So, I am quite fixing the errors won't reduce the quality of your manuscript, hence, it will/might not lead to any rejection.
And as a side note, some editors are really slow to respond and often takes months to publish. So, you got to have a lot of patience during this whole process. You are in a hurry to see your research published, but the editors are not!

Actually, the article has been accepted and currently is in the production phase.
